# xilinx fpga resource estimation

Tags: fpga, xilinx

I am trying to understand how to estimate FPGA resource requirement for a design/application.

Lets says Spartan 7 part has, Logic Cells - 52160 DSP Slices - 120 Memory - 2700

How to find out number of CLB's, RAM, and Flash availability?

Lets say my design needs a SPI interface in FPGA, How to estimate CLB, RAM and Flash requirement for this design?

Thanks

Comment: You cannot estimate as simple as that because it depends on many optimization parameters conveyed to the tool, your coding style etc, not just the part number. You synthesise, and the tool will give you the exact numbers.

Comment: Would [this](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/white_papers/wp496-comp-perf-util.pdf) help? There are similar tables for logic functions as well.

Comment: @MituRaj I agree. Its not simple but there should be a way to do rough estimation in order to select the fpga part/pin count.

Comment: There's not enough information on what are your assumptions cz there are N number of variables . You can describe an spi interface in RTL that consumes wide range of resources depending on what was the optimisation goal. What were the features of this SPI etc.

Comment: @MituRaj So you are saying we cannot estimate without the design details?

Answer (score 0):

Though it won't be accurate for your design and FPGA, it is helpful to see the usage as reported on existing cores even on other FPGAs. For example, on a Cyclone 10, [this](https://github.com/jakubcabal/spi-fpga) SPI master and slave IP core uses 34 logic elements and 23 flip flops. One Cyclone 10 logic element has one 4LUT and a register. In the document [DS180 - 7-Series Overview](https://www.xilinx.com/content/dam/xilinx/support/documentation/data_sheets/ds180_7Series_Overview.pdf), you will find that the part with "52160 logic cells", the XC7S50, has 8150 "slices" and 600 kilobit RAM. It also says each Spartan 7 slice has four LUTs and eight flip-flops. More information can be found in [UG474 - 7 Series FPGAs Configurable Logic Block User Guide](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/user_guides/ug474_7Series_CLB.pdf). Here you find out that one slice (=half a CLB) has two 5LUTs. So you get 16k LUTs, and you can fit in >400 SPI cores, as far as LUTs are concerned. More specifics can be found in the docs. Such as that your device has a total of 65200 flip flops, so it won't get bottlenecked by those.